# how to get php/apache to schedule tasks using the AT daemon

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

is there a way to enable a php script (apache user) to schedule a task using the AT daemon?

I would like to pipe the task to the atd from my php script like this:

```
exec( "echo 'date > /some/dir/date.txt' | at now + 1 minute > /dev/null &" );
```

when I run the php script from the command line (root) everything is fine,
however, when I run the script via a http request the at job is never created.

I am aware that apache doesn't have shell access, is there any work around available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec()` does not use a shell so you can't use pipes etc..

Use backticks, `shell_exec()` or `system()` instead to make it work.

```
shell_exec("echo 'date > /some/dir/date.txt' | at now + 1 minute");
```

Comment: tnx ThiefMaster, using shell_exec my error_log shows "shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons". I'm not sure what the implications would be if I were to enable it.

Comment: Usually shared hosting companies disable it via php.ini because they don't want php applications to run shell commands. Usually they have really poor security (all customers in the same user group and thus only restricted by things like open_basedir from nosing around other customers' files - and shell commands obviously circumvent that restriction)

Answer (score 0):

If the account your script runs under (Apache or a cgi user) does not have shell access, at will not work, because the disfunctional shell (like /bin/bad) will be tried to run the command later on.

Check if you can exec anything:

```
$output = array();
exec('whoami',$output);
print_r($output);
```

If this does work, you could try something like (pseudocode):

```
write "date > /some/dir/date.txt" in /tmp/atcmd
exec("/usr/bin/at -f /tmp/atcmd now + 1 minute");
```

So you need:
- A shell to run the command in, later on
- Permision inside php to run the exec function
- No problems created by /etc/at.{deny,allow}

This basically means (I guess) you need a PHP that runs in php-cgi switched to a "real" account.

The only other solution I can think of right now is to create the script you need on the webserver, and to run the at job on a machine you do have access to, using wget.

```
echo "wget -q http://myserver.mydomain/my/atscript"  | at now + 1 minute
```

People actually use such constructs for cron-like behaviour. Hey, I might even setup a service for stuff like that on my hosting service :-)